# How can I properly include a css file in my index.html file in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find an answer. I am building a website with React, and I want to include a stylesheet. My React app has the index.html file and I created a line in the file that says:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homePage.css">`

but React won't load the css. How do I do this properly?

Sidenote: React also doesn't load images. When I put a line of code in my JSX like this:

`<a href="./my_resume.pdf"><img id="resume" src="./views/icons/resume_logo.png" /></a>`

React won't load the image. Please help, I've been banging my head against my desk about this for a while now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say "React won't import the css", what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I should've said load the css. Even though I provide the link, the css is not applied to the html when I visit the page. @hackerrdave

Comment: when you visit network tab in dev tools - whats the info for that request?

Comment: I get 3 errors when I inspect saying: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` for jquery.min.js:1, bootstrap.min.js:1, and clean-blog.min.js:1

Comment: @CameronPayton Please Select an answer to help others who come across this question

Answer (score 3):

in your html file all you need to do is a normal link statement

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/journal/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1L94saFXWAvEw88RkpRz8r28eQMvt7kG9ux3DdCqya/P3CfLNtgqzMnyaUa49Pl2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Like so that one is from a website but you can do the same thing with a local one like

```
<link src="/styles/maincss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

that will work

Comment: this saved my broken UI when doing manual reload on the page, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely with the location of your files and the way in which you're referencing them. For example, is `my_resume.pdf` in the same folder as `index.html`? Is `homePage.css` also in the same folder?

The prefix `/` is relative to the **root** directory.

The prefix `./` is relative to the **working** directory.

The prefix `../` is relative to the **parent** directory.

For further information regarding relative and absolute URLs, I recommend checking out [Coffee Cup's article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) on the topic.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Cameron Payton !
can you using relative paths for it. Instead you use absolute paths.
Example:
http://your-domain/homePage.css
and 
http://your-domain/views/icons/resume_logo.png

I think it will help you. Please get back to me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include css in your html, you need to put them in your public folder instead of SRC folder and use '%PUBLIC_URL%' as the path to your css. So it would look something like this:

```
<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/homePage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But, it is highly recommended that you do import the css that you want inside your react component, because your css would get minified and bundled. So you could do something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// ... rest of imports
import './path/to/css/homePage.css'
```

For more info on this, go to the documentation [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder).